# Is there an equivalent to __DATE__ in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm looking for an equivalent to C/C++'s `__TIME__` and `__DATE__` compile-time constants in AS3. I want to be able to bake in when the swf was built.

I can write a build script or JSFL to update a constant somewhere, but I was hoping there was something built in.

Comment: __TIME__ and __DATE__ are come from what language? Or you mean compiler variables?

Comment: `__TIME__` and `__DATE__` are stubs in the old action script 2 language that would be filled in by the system at runtime.

Comment: Yeah I'm looking for a compile-time solution for AS3.

Answer (score 0):

It is just for both `__DATE__` and `__TIME__`

```
new Date();
```

See this example below for how it might be used. You can find the [documentation here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/Date.html).

```
/**
 * Called by the parent container when the display is being drawn.
 */
public override function draw():void
{
    // stores the current date and time in an instance variable
    currentTime = new Date();
    showTime(currentTime);
}

/**
 * Displays the given Date/Time in that good old analog clock style.
 */
public function showTime(time:Date):void 
{
    // gets the time values
    var seconds:uint = time.getSeconds();
    var minutes:uint = time.getMinutes();
    var hours:uint = time.getHours();

    // multiplies by 6 to get degrees
    this.secondHand.rotation = 180 + (seconds * 6);
    this.minuteHand.rotation = 180 + (minutes * 6);

    // Multiply by 30 to get basic degrees, then
    // add up to 29.5 degrees (59 * 0.5)
    // to account for the minutes.
    this.hourHand.rotation = 180 + (hours * 30) + (minutes * 0.5);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I meant __DATE__ and __TIME__ from the C/C++ world. Compile time constants, not runtime. I'll update the question.